# elasticsearch need to add a must to a bool should query

Tags: elasticsearch, filter

I have the following query that works as expected:

```
GET <index_name>/_search
{        
    "sort": [
      {
        "irFileCreateTime": {
        "order": "desc"
       }
     }
    ],
    "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "match": {
                "fileId": 46704
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "fileId": 46706
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "fileId": 46719
              }
            }
          ]
        }
     }
}
```

The problem is that I need to further filter the data, but the field I need to filter on is a text field.  I have tried many different ways of putting a must match into my query but everything is either malformed or filters out all hits when I know it should only filter out half.  How can I add a must match "irStatus":"COMPLETE" to this query?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you're after is a `term` query on, preferably, the `keyword` of `irStatus`. That is to say:

```
GET index/_search
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "irFileCreateTime": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "irStatus.keyword": {
              "value": "COMPLETE"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "fileId": 46704
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "fileId": 46706
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "fileId": 46719
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Assuming your mapping looks something like this:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "irFileCreateTime": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "fileId": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "irStatus": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The reason it's apparently failing on your end is that "COMPLETE" has been lowercased due to `standard` analyzer.

---

Alternatively, you could do:

```
{
  "must":[
    {
      "query_string":{
        "query":"irStatus:COMPLETE AND (fileId:(46704 OR 46706 OR 46719))"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```